# Server Side Paging with KendoUI's Listview control

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I am trying to do server side paging with KendoUI's ListView control. But the problem is that the pager control does not show the links for the pages. Here is my code:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 2,

                schema: {
                    id: "Id",
                    data: "Results",
                    total: "total"                            
                    }
                },

                transport: {
                    read: function (options) {
                        oThis.GetDataFromServer(options);
                    }
                }
            });

$('#listcontent').kendoListView({
                template: kendo.template('<div><table > \
                                          <tr><td style = "\\padding:8px;" ><b>#:data.Name#</b></td ></tr> \
                                          <tr><td style="\\padding:8px;">#:data.Description#</td > \
                                         <td><a href="#:data.productdetailurl(data.SourceProductVersionId,"catalogueitem")#">View Detail</a ></td> \
                                          </tr></table></div>'),
                dataSource: dataSource,
                selectable: true
            });

            //render kendo listview pager
            $('#listpager').kendoPager({
                datasource: dataSource 
            });
```

the total field contains correct number of records. This is working fine with Grid so not sure what is the issue with Listview.

Comment: The data source option of your pager isn't properly spelled. Should be "dataSource" not "datasource".

Answer (score 2):

I think you left out `pageable: true`

```
$('#listcontent').kendoListView({
            template: kendo.template('<div><table > \
                                      <tr><td style = "\\padding:8px;" ><b>#:data.Name#</b></td ></tr> \
                                      <tr><td style="\\padding:8px;">#:data.Description#</td > \
                                     <td><a href="#:data.productdetailurl(data.SourceProductVersionId,"catalogueitem")#">View Detail</a ></td> \
                                      </tr></table></div>'),
            dataSource: dataSource,
            selectable: true,
            pageable: true
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have tried that as well but didnt work. I am beginning to think that server side paging does not work with listview :( because all the samples I am seeing are related to the grid

Comment: Can you get paging to work where serverPaging: false?

Comment: ok I changed serverPaging to false and commented total field in schema. but still same result :(

Comment: Paging definitely works with ListView.  You are missing something in your code OR maybe it's your version of Kendo.  Here is the demo that shows paging working.  I'm sure you've seen it.  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/listview/index.html

Comment: ok I just tried paging on local data and it is working perfectly.

Comment: how can I find out how many total records datasource is seeing when I set total: "total" in schema?

Comment: var count = listcontent.dataSource.total();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50965/discussion-between-haris-and-rick-s)